# React native element renderErrorMessage

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

I am trying to show error message conditionally on **react native element** input component but seems like it doesn't work

```
      <Input
        label="Email"
        leftIcon={<MaterialIcon name="email" size={24} color="#f8dc81" />}
        onChangeText={(value) => setEmail(value)}
        value={email}
        renderErrorMessage={false}
        errorMessage="Enter valid email"
      />
```

Expected behavior that it will not display error message but it displays

Answer (score 1):

As doc [renderErrorMessage](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/input/#rendererrormessage) is to handle the space taken by the errorMessage.

```
If the error message container should be rendered (take up vertical space). If false, when showing errorMessage, the layout will shift to add it at that time.
```

So if [errorMessage](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/input/#errormessage) is present it will show error, even if `renderErrorMessage` is false